# Code=1001 "No fill" error in Facebook Audience Network

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I am integrating Facebook audience network in my iOS project for the first time. Every thing is as perfect as described in the official documentation.

But still I am getting this error every time I run the app.

> Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No fill, FBAdErrorDetailKey={
>       msg = "No fill"

I am doing my project in swift btw. and this is the site I have followed for audience network integration:
https://www.appcoda.com/facebook-ads-integration/

Please help me out of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue and resolve it using this bellow Code.

```
[FBAdSettings addTestDevice:[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash]];
    FBNativeAd *nativeAd = [[FBNativeAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"598719620275857_842169869264163"];
    nativeAd.delegate = self;
    nativeAd.mediaCachePolicy = FBNativeAdsCachePolicyAll;
    [nativeAd loadAd];
```

This code is for only test mode ids,
Have to remove **[FBAdSettings addTestDevice:[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash]];** while app live.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test facebook Test ads then the above methods will work,

But If you want to display real Ads, you have to fill in your payout details.

Answer (score 0):

Audience Network sends targeted ads based on the Facebook profile associated with the device. If you have Facebook installed and logged in but still see a "No Fill" error, you should consider enabling Test Ads.

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing

> ...you can enable test ads on an iOS device by adding the following line of code before loading an ad:
>
> `[FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@”HASHED_ID”];`